# NHibernate Search Index poco object throws TransientObjectException

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate.search

When calling Index method on FullTextSession with plain poco object throws the error below, works fine with proxied object.

Stacktrace:

[TransientObjectException: the instance was not associated with this session]
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.GetIdentifier(Object obj) +500

I'm trying to squeeze the performance out of the nhibernate select method I've got the following code:

```
    public virtual IList<T> LoadSearch()
    {
        return Adapater.Session.QueryOver<T>()
            .SelectList(e =>
            {
                e.Select(x => x.Id);
                e.Select(x => x.Title);
                e.Select(x => x.Description);
                return e;
            }).List<object[]>()
            .Select(props => new T
            {
                Id = (Guid)props[0],
                Title = (string)props[1],
                Description = (string)props[2]
            }).ToList();
    }
```

Is there way to return a proxied result? or some how adapt the list to a proxied list?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only index objects that are associated with a session, i.e. proxied entities.

The plain POCOs you are returning didn't come from NH - so aren't associated with a NH session.

You could try using `ISession.Lock(instance, NHibernate.LockMode.None);` on each entity to associate it with the session, but I really don't know if that'd work.

Comment: Not sure that's going to work as to reattach I think you have to call update() on the session to reattach. Once the session gets flushed it will end up overwriting the current entries in the database.

Comment: Given up on this path, I've altered the fluent mappings to lazy load associations and properties on my domain model. I've achieved the same result but with the additional benefit of objects coming back wrapped in an NHibernate proxy.